# UbuntuServer, graphics-card died, cant log in to use SSH/VNS

Tags: 10.04, ssh, login, vnc, remote

Okay, weird situation.
I have a really old desktop and yesterday I decided to setup ubuntu-server as a home server on that thing. It has no onboard graphics.
I installed gnome-desktop, so at the start of the server, I have to log in.

Today I restarted it, and it looks like the graphics card died.
I get no signal on the monitor. I can't use SSH or VNS, because the services start after I log in...

Is there a way to log in over the network? cmd? net use?
Can someone tell me what keys I have to press to log in? So I can try to do it blindy and then setup auto-login.

I tried to press Enter after the boot to select the user "Administrator" and then typed the password and enter again, but it wouldnt log in because SSH/VNC still won't work.

Ubuntu-Server 10.04 32-bit. Reeaally old computer. No other graphics-card I could use. Already tried different VGA/DVI cables...

TL;DR: Ubuntu-Server with Gnome Desktop is started and hanging at the login-screen. Graphics-card died so I cant see it. Have to remotely log in to enable auto-login.

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl-Alt-F1 or Ctrl-Alt-F2 to switch to the console mode. Then type in your username and press return. Afterwards enter your password and press enter.
"sudo /etc/init.d/ssh start" should start the ssh server.